# how to use cookies saved by libcurl in httpwebrequest?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, cookies, httpwebrequest

I developed an application for posting however it does not work with multithreading some issue in the posting method for `libcurl` which i cannot resolve.So i want to use `HTTPWEBREQUEST` instead .

I have the cookies saved in txt files with accounts username, how can i  use them in `HTTPWEBREQUEST`

In simple my question  is how to retrieve cookies from txt files saved by `libcurl` into  `cookie container` so i can use it with `HTTPWEBREQUEST`

The txt files are like:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

www.example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   10  _lipt   deleteMe
.example.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   1407285025  bcookie "v=2&20ed7c4b-de0d-4a49-9e89-b2260988e566"
www.example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   1351985424  leo_auth_token  "LIM:187682881:a:1344209425:6b1292e2a3dfd0f7f40d4fc7bb196457ca9f3e04"
www.example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   10  sl  "delete me"
www.example.com FALSE   /   TRUE    0   s_leo_auth_token    "LIM:187682881:s:1344209425:eb957b29be2d103d418a49888733167af66c37cd"
www.example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   0   JSESSIONID  "ajax:00000000000000"
www.example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   1407285025  visit   "v=1&M"
www.example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   10  li_a    "delete me"
www.example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   10  mst "delete me"
www.example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   10  li_at   "delete me"
.example.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   0   lang    "v=2&lang=en-us"
www.example.com FALSE   /uas/   FALSE   0   X-LI-IDC    C1
www.example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   0   X-LI-IDC    C1
```

UPDATE

DOES the webbrowser also have cookies int he same way which we can retrive using:

```
                string[] array = webBrowser1.Document.Cookie.Split(new char[]
                        {
                            ';'
                        });
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    string cookie = array[i];
                    string name = cookie.Split(new char[]
                            {
                                '='
                            })[0];
                    string value = cookie.Substring(name.Length + 1);
                    string path = "/";
                    string domain = "turn14.com";
                    yummycookies.Add(new Cookie(name.Trim(), value.Trim(), path, domain));
                }
```

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `CookieContainer`, which stores cookied for HttpWebRequest.

You can parse the cookies from the file and add them to the CookieContainer.

Comment: I get all the cookies save to cookie container and create WEBREQUEST but it does not work , i get html (moved temporarily) ? And with this cookie file it works fine with libcurl